# VS Code Intellisense for javascript not giving suggestions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-completion

[image: picture]

Is there a way to get suggestions like `div.appendChild` here?

It feels like I'm missing a lot of suggestions.

Stuff like addEventListener doesn't show up.

Or is that just something that isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can achive intelisense by two ways

A. Is to create them by yourself by configuring the global snippet
[configure snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets)

B. is to download an extension with snippets for example "react food truck" for react snippets